# JHipster Cannot find the class file for org.thymeleaf.context.WebContext

Tags: jhipster

I've generated first JHipster application and resolved Maven and pom issues. I'm using Eclipse and now getting this compilation error: "Cannot find the class file for org.thymeleaf.context.WebContext". Not sure what I'm missing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have to resolve any Maven issue after generation, it's supposed to work out of the box:

- If you have some pom error just after generation, please fill up a ticket
- If you have changed your Maven configuration in some way, after generation, and then you have a Thymeleaf error, then chances are that it's your changes that broke up the system